# redis fault injection using istio and envoy filter

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

I am trying to inject 2s delay to a redis instance (which is not in cluster) using istio.
So, first I am creating an `ExternalName` k8s service in order to reach external redis so that istio knows about this service. This works. However when I create `EnvoyFilter` to add fault, I don't see `redis_proxy` filter in `istioctl pc listeners <pod-name> -o json` for a pod in same namespace. (and also delay is not introduced)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: chaos
  labels:
    istio-injection: enabled
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-proxy
  namespace: chaos
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: redis-external.bla
  ports:
    - name: tcp
      protocol: TCP
      port: 6379
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: redis-proxy-filter
  namespace: chaos
spec:
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: NETWORK_FILTER
      match:
        listener:
          portNumber: 6379
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: "envoy.filters.network.redis_proxy"
      patch:
        operation: MERGE
        value:
          name: "envoy.filters.network.redis_proxy"
          typed_config:
            "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.redis_proxy.v3.RedisProxy
            faults:
              - fault_type: DELAY
                fault_enabled:
                  default_value:
                    numerator: 100
                    denominator: HUNDRED
                delay: 2s
```

Can someone give an idea? Thanks.

Comment: You are not explaining yourself. This statement `So, first I am creating an ExternalName k8s service in order to reach external redis so that istio knows about this service.` is completely wrong. `ExternalName` type `Service` is a k8s object, and has nothing to do with Istio. `ServiceEntry` is an Istio object to add external endpoints to Istio rgistry. I don't know if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your yaml in my local istio 1.8.2. Here's few changes that might help you

- set PILOT_ENABLE_REDIS_FILTER in istiod env var. otherwise, the filter name will be "name": "envoy.filters.network.tcp_proxy"
- add match context

  ```
  match:
    context: SIDECAR_OUTBOUND
  ```
- use redis protocol

  ```
  ports:
    - name: redis-proxy
      port: 6379
      appProtocol: redis
  ```

I can see the following

```
% istioctl pc listener nginx.chaos --port 6379 -o json
[
    {
        "name": "0.0.0.0_6379",
        "address": {
            "socketAddress": {
                "address": "0.0.0.0",
                "portValue": 6379
            }
        },
        "filterChains": [
            {
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "name": "envoy.filters.network.redis_proxy",
                        "typedConfig": {
                            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.redis_proxy.v3.RedisProxy",
                            "statPrefix": "outbound|6379||redis-proxy.chaos.svc.cluster.local",
                            "settings": {
                                "opTimeout": "5s"
                            },
                            "latencyInMicros": true,
                            "prefixRoutes": {
                                "catchAllRoute": {
                                    "cluster": "outbound|6379||redis-proxy.chaos.svc.cluster.local"
                                }
                            },
                            "faults": [
                                {
                                    "faultEnabled": {
                                        "defaultValue": {
                                            "numerator": 100
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "delay": "2s"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "deprecatedV1": {
            "bindToPort": false
        },
        "trafficDirection": "OUTBOUND"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried all your suggestions except: `appProtocol: redis`, because current feature gate in our cluster does not allow this. I can see the filter configuration in listeners json.. but there is some connection issue: 
```root@redis-cli:/data# redis-cli -h redis-proxy.chaos.svc.cluster.local -p 6379
redis-proxy.chaos.svc.cluster.local:6379> ping
PONG
redis-proxy.chaos.svc.cluster.local:6379> dbsize
(error) invalid request```
Also I was thinking that redis filter will be added to only pods in same namespace.. but I can see redis filter in all pods in other namespaces too. any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have redis svc to test end-to-end. You might want to try adding runtime-key as mentioned in envoy docs .  and play around with the values. https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/listeners/network_filters/redis_proxy_filter
          
```
- delay: 2s
             fault_enabled:
               default_value:
                 denominator: MILLION
                 numerator: 1000000
               runtime_key: bogus_key
             fault_type: DELAY
```

Comment: changing service port name from `redis-proxy` to `tcp-proxy` solves the connection issue but then redis filter configuration disappears in pod proxy-config listeners json so delay is not applied. Double checked, `PILOT_ENABLE_REDIS_FILTER` is enabled. So connection works with `tcp` protocol but not with `redis` protocol.

Comment: since I don't have redis service outside, I tested redis helm chart installed in my local cluster. I changed k8s service or redis-master to use redis protocol. I added 200s delay. then I run redis-cli from client pod. I can do ping as well as getting the delay.  redis-master:6379> get abc
(error) upstream failure
(199.77s)
redis-master:6379> ping PONG
PONG